# Rails error Couldn't find Blog with 'id'=new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a weird error when I want to redirect users to the root_url when they try to access `blogs/new` url in my app. 
My routes are

```
resources :blogs, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :comments, only: [:create]
end

namespace :admin do
  resources :blogs
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :new, :destroy]
end
```

My non-admin blogs controller looks like this:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_blog, only: [:show]


  def show
    unless @blog
      redirect_to blogs_path
      flash[:notice] = "You are not authorized to create a post."
    end
  end

  def index
    @blogs = Blog.all
  end

  private

    def set_blog
      @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

I get the error `Couldn't find Blog with 'id'=new`.

Comment: Whenever you're having some routing issue, it's a good idea to show us your `routes.rb`. You should also post the portion of the view where the error occurs. Finally, please take the time to describe the problem clearly and properly by laying out each step required to reproduce the problem, along with what happens at each step.

Answer (score 0):

In rails, the priority of routes goes from top to bottom. Meaning, when you try to hit `/blogs/new`, the route gets matched with the `show` action of `blogs` defined in the top of your `routes.rb`.

`blogs/new` gets matched with `/blogs/:id` which is mapped to `blogs#show` action.

In the `set_blog` method, `params[:id]` is `new` and since there is no record with the id of `new`, you're getting that weird error.

How to get around this? Change the priority of your routes.

Move the following block below the `admin` namespaced routes.

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :blogs
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :new, :destroy]
end

resources :blogs, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :comments, only: [:create]
end
```

By the way, your question says that you want to avoid non-admin users to access `blogs#new`. If that's the case, you should try to hit `/admin/blogs/new` and not `/blogs/new`.

If you had done that, you wouldn't have gotten the error in the first place. But still, its good to know about the priority of routes in rails.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Then I should really say that whenever a request to the blogs/new url is hit it should redirect to the root_url with a warning. I want to redirect whenever the params[:id] doesn't exist. I found a solution by replacing find with find_by_id that actually returns false, which allows me to run a conditional on the object.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. `/blogs/new` doesn't even exist for non-admin users. For a normal user to access that page, he should hit `/admin/blogs/new`. You got the error because of the priority of routes. Does this make sense?

Comment: I understood your point about the route not existing. My confusion was that I thought #find was returning nil when the value in params was non-existent. It wasn't so I had to change the method. So whether the requested url was blogs/new or blogs/whatever I wanted a redirect to occur.

Comment: @Coder_Nick If thats you want, you can rescue `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception and then redirect the user.